# Angularjs best way to dynamically change CSS class based on input query

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the AngularJS [phonecat tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00), there is an input box which is used to apply a filter to ng-repeat.  This works great for returning a subset array to display on the screen.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">
  <ul class="phones">
```

...

```
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I was wondering what's the best way to dynamically add a CSS class to matching elements.  An example use case of this would be to add a background-color (style .matching{}) to all matching elements.

Comparing the query text in ng-class did NOT work:

```
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones" class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
      <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" ng-class="{'matching': phone.name.indexOf(query) != -1 }">{{phone.name}}</a>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I am new to angular and trying to just get a feel for the framework.  Do I have to bind the query text to the element somehow so that the comparison works?  Would a better approach be to handle this through a custom directive?

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the class to a function in the controller. `ng-class="GetMatchingClass(phone)"`

```
$scope.GetMatchingClass= function(phone){
    if(phone.name.indexOf(query) != -1 ){return "matching"}
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This ended up working - thanks!  I guess ng-Class has two-way data binding as well, so I wouldn't have to link each <li> to ng-Model='query'.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" ng-class="{'matching': phone.name==query }">{{phone.name}}</a>
```

that should do it for exact matches.